# Limit of succession involved with e

Tags: analysis, limits

I'm having some troubles calculating the limit for this succession: $(1-\frac2n)^{\frac1n}$.
I already solved a similar limit for $(1+\frac2{\sqrt {n}})^{3\sqrt{n}}$ by placing $Y_n = \frac{\sqrt{n}}2$, but when I try to do something similar for this succession I get strange things at the exponent. Any help please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $n$ goes to $+\infty$, 
$\frac{1}{n}$  and $\frac{2}{n}$
tend to $0$.

so the limit of your sequence is

$(1-0)^0=1^0=1$.

Comment: Oh god... I was so concentrated on strange stuff that I completely forgot to look at the single numbers... thanks man